# Why is this Angular model not completely overwritten?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm encountering a strange issue where a model is not completely overwritten after a new property has been set on it in a directive.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Dashboard">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items" my-dir items="items"></div>
        <button ng-click="replaceItems()">Replace</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('Dashboard', function($scope) {

    $scope.items = [{foo: "bar"}];

    console.log($scope.items);

    $scope.replaceItems = function () {
        $scope.items = [{}];

        console.log($scope.items);

    }

}).directive('myDir', function($injector) {
    return {
        scope: {
            items: '='
        },
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.items.newThing = 'I am new';
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tgzdt/

Try clicking Replace and check the console.

Why is newThing still there even though $scope.items is overwritten with a blank array and object?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reset the `items`, write:

```
$scope.items = [];
```

In your case you create empty object `{}` therefore you invoke directive as well.

For that reason the directive adds `newThing = 'I am new';` to your empty object.

If you want to make it work with `$scope.items = [{}]`, write directive like:

```
.directive('myDir', function($injector) {
    return {
        scope: {
            items: '='
        },
        link: function(scope) {            
            if(scope.items[0].foo !== undefined){  // dummy validation
                 scope.items.newThing = 'I am new';
            }            
        }
    };
});
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tgzdt/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

When `items` change, the directive is fired again.

Put a console.log in the directive and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
scope.items.newThing = 'I am new';
```

Is just adding a new property "newThing" on the $scope.items object, not overwriting it.
If you expand the object in Chrome console, you will see :

> ```
> Array[1] 
> 0: Object 
>     $$hashKey: "004" 
>     foo: "bar"
>     __proto__: Object 
> length: 1 
> newThing: "I am new"
> __proto__: Array[0]
> ```